# Scatter plot with color label and legend specified by c option

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I'd like to make [this kind of scatter plot](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html) where the points have colors specified by the "c" option and the legend shows the color's meanings.

The data source of mine is like following:

```
scatter_x = [1,2,3,4,5]
scatter_y = [5,4,3,2,1]
group = [1,3,2,1,3] # each (x,y) belongs to the group 1, 2, or 3.
```

I tried this:

```
plt.scatter(scatter_x, scatter_y, c=group, label=group)
plt.legend()
```

Unfortunately, I did not get the legend as expected. How to show the legend properly? I expected there are five rows and each row shows the color and group correspondences.

[image]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As in the example you mentioned, call `plt.scatter` for each group:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

scatter_x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
scatter_y = np.array([5,4,3,2,1])
group = np.array([1,3,2,1,3])
cdict = {1: 'red', 2: 'blue', 3: 'green'}

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for g in np.unique(group):
    ix = np.where(group == g)
    ax.scatter(scatter_x[ix], scatter_y[ix], c = cdict[g], label = g, s = 100)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

check this out:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as  np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scatter_x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
scatter_y = np.array([5,4,3,2,1])
group = np.array([1,3,2,1,3])
for g in np.unique(group):
    i = np.where(group == g)
    ax.scatter(scatter_x[i], scatter_y[i], label=g)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```