# How to create a legend based on multiple colors?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I currently have a graph of exoplanets' insolation vs density, with different colors contributing to different orbit periods. I have the color situation figured out, I'm just confused on how to set the legend. Here's what I have.

```
plt.figure(figsize = (9,7))
plt.title('Insolation vs Density', fontsize = 24, 
fontweight='bold')
plt.xlabel('Density [g/cm$^3$]', fontsize = 16)
plt.ylabel('Insolation [Earth Flux]', fontsize=16)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
x = data['Density [g/cm**3]']
y = data['Insolation [Earth Flux]']
z = data['Orbital Period']

def pltcolor(lst):
    cols=[]
    for i in data['Orbital Period']:
        if i <= 3:
            cols.append('mediumturquoise'),
        elif i >= 20 :
            cols.append('blue'),
        else:
            cols.append('crimson')
    return cols
cols=pltcolor(z)

plt.scatter(x=x,y=y,c=cols)
plt.scatter(circum_data['Density [g/cm**3]'],circum_data['Insolation [Earth Flux]'], color = 'fuchsia', label = 
Circumbinary Planets')
plt.legend();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, you need to call `plt.scatter` for each group. For reference take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006268/matplotlib-scatter-plot-with-color-label-and-legend-specified-by-c-option). Right now you are figuring out what each of the data points colors should be and then assigning them a color in `cols`. Then you are calling `plt.scatter` once and it plots all the points and assigns colors accordingly. However, matplotlib still thinks all those points are from the same group. So when you call `plt.legend()` it only gives a single label.

I have tried to make a work around for you using your code. It was a little bit tricky because you removed the data from your example (understandably). I am assuming that your data is a list, and so created some fake data to test my approach.

So my approach is as follows: go through your data and if your z data lies inside a specific range you assign it to a new array. Once you have processed all your data for that group (z range) plot it. Then repeat this for each of the groups. I have attached a sample of what I am thinking below. There are possibly cleaner ways of doing this. However, the overall approach is the same. Try and plot each group individually.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

# Fake data I created
data = {}
data['Density [g/cm**3]'] = [10,15, 31, 24,55]
data['Insolation [Earth Flux]'] = [10,15,8,4,55]
data['Orbital Period'] = [10,15,3,2,55]

circum_data = {}
circum_data['Density [g/cm**3]'] = [10,15,7,5,55]
circum_data['Insolation [Earth Flux]'] = [10,15,4,3,55]

# ----- Your code------
plt.figure(figsize = (9,7))
plt.title('Insolation vs Density', fontsize = 24, fontweight='bold')
plt.xlabel('Density [g/cm$^3$]', fontsize = 16)
plt.ylabel('Insolation [Earth Flux]', fontsize=16)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
x = data['Density [g/cm**3]']
y = data['Insolation [Earth Flux]']
z = data['Orbital Period']
# -----------------

# Created the ranges you want
distances_max = [3, 20, math.inf]
distances_min = [-1*math.inf, 3, 20]
# Select you colors
colors = ['mediumturquoise', 'blue', 'crimson']
# The legend names you want
names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']

# For each of the ranges
for i in range(len(names)):
    # Create a new group of data
    col = []
    data_x = []
    data_y = []
    # Go through your data and put it in the group if it is inside the range
    for (xi, yi, zi) in zip(x, y, z): 
        if distances_min[i] < zi <= distances_max[i]:
            col.append(colors[i])
            data_x.append(xi) 
            data_y.append(yi) 

    # Plot the group of data
    plt.scatter(x=data_x,y=data_y,c=colors[i], label=names[i])   


# plt.scatter(circum_data['Density [g/cm**3]'],
#             circum_data['Insolation [Earth Flux]'],
#             color = 'fuchsia',
#             label ='Circumbinary Planets')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Running this code produces the following outputs where name1, name2, name3 are defined in the `names` list.

[image: Example graph]

I hope this helped. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could have your legend labels (let's call it "labels") in a vector of the same length as your "x" vector, and just do:

```
plt.legend(labels)
```

You can also do it differently (I think that's what you're trying to do): you could just plot each group in a loop and set the label. It would be something like:

```
for i,group in enumerate(groups):
    plt.scatter(x[group],y[group],label=group_names[i])
plt.legend()
```