# How can I plot the legend or label of kmeans clustered data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scikit-learn, k-means

I've clustered some data using `kmeans` and have plotted it using `scatterplot`

```
clusters = 3
model = KMeans(n_clusters=clusters, init='k-means++', n_init=10)

model.fit(features)
labels = model.labels_

plt.scatter(features[:, 0], features[:, 1], c=model.labels_, alpha=0.75)
plt.scatter(model.cluster_centers_[:, 0], model.cluster_centers_[:, 1], marker='x')
plt.show()
```

The above lines can plot my clustered data as seen from below

[image]

But it is not showing me which color represents which cluster? How can I plot the legend accompanying this plot? For example, yellow: cluster 1, purple: cluster 2, teal: cluster 3?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what were your results? For example, matplotlib has a good [legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html) that shows the basics of adding and editing a legend for a plot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib scatter plot with color label and legend specified by c option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006268/matplotlib-scatter-plot-with-color-label-and-legend-specified-by-c-option)

Comment: @Ewran, Thank you. The linked answer did help. I did try this before but did not use a loop as suggested, thats why I was not getting the expected result