# plot kmeans clusters with legend and marker to each cluster and color

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, k-means

I want to make a figure for K-means clustering results, each cluster has a different color, a different marker, and a legend.Could you please suggest a script to draw the figure?.

df is the data set of features x,y,z and different kmeans results as features in the following way:

```
df['c2']=kmeans2_lables_
df['c3']=kmeans3_lables_
```

I tried to use this code s far, but it is not working and does not have a marker.

```
def draw_figures(clust_col):
    lables={2:{0:'Low',1:'High'},3:{0:'Medium',1:'Low',2:'High'},5:{0:'Very High',1:'Very Low',2:'High',3:'Medium',4:'Low'}}
    cdict = {0: 'r', 1: 'b', 2: 'g',3:'c',4:'y'}
    #group=range(clust_col)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for g in np.unique(df[clust_col]):
        ix = np.where(df[clust_col] == g)
        ax.scatter(df[ix]['f'], df[ix]['avg'], c = cdict[g], label = labels[clust_col][g], s = 100)
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been close to what you are asking with the following code:

```
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('Dark2', 4)

plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], alpha=.4, c=kmeans.labels_, cmap=cmap)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.colorbar(ticks=[])
plt.show()
```

Check the plotted results [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLsTP.png)

What I am doing is to select a discrete colormap with `cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('Dark2', 4)`, then I indicate plotly to use it adding `cmap=cmap` to the `plt.scatter`.

I add the colorbar with `plt.colorbar`, but erasing confusing ticks with `ticks=[]`.

Looking for similar solutions, I found this: [matplotlib scatter plot with color label and legend specified by c option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006268/matplotlib-scatter-plot-with-color-label-and-legend-specified-by-c-option) that might also help you.